# How to call function in twig in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony

In my model (Task) I have a function:

```
public function isTaskOverdue()
    {
        if ("now"|date('Y-m-d') > task.deadline|date('Y-m-d')){
            return false;

        } else{
            return true;
        }
    }
```

In twig (edit) I want to display form:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}app:Resources:Task:edit{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

        {{ form(form) }}

{% endblock %}
```

I want to display form, if this function return true.
How can I call this function in twig?

Comment: In php, you can compare 2 dates directly, no need to format them. It twig you need to apply the date filter to get the "now" date.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the task entity to twig and call method from object task :

```
{% if task.isTaskOverdue %}
    {{ form(form) }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I changed my code to look like that, but some error appeared: Variable "task" does not exist in Task/edit.html.twig at line 7

Comment: You need to pass object Task  from controller. to  twig. Here an example: `code`  return $this->render(
            'main/main_wrapper.html.twig',
           ['task' => $task]
        );  `code`

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be your controller that receives the function result and display the form or not depending on it.

Also you can write your function like so :

```
public function isTaskOverdue()
    {
        return ("now"|date('Y-m-d') > task.deadline|date('Y-m-d'));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the task entity to twig and do :

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}app:Resources:Task:edit{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

    {% if "now"|date("Ymd") <= task.deadline|date("Ymd") %}

        {{ form(form) }}

     {% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

**But, caution :**

If you just not display the form, there is a security issue, because if an attacker submit the form from an self rebuilded HTML page, your controller will receive the form data and apply it.

So I would do the check in the controller, and only create and pass the form to the twig template if the condition is true.

Then, in twig you can use :

```
{% if form is defined %}
    {{ form(form) }}
{% endif %}
```